# New to firebase auth and android development

Tags: android, firebase

I am pretty new to android development and Firebase(the new google one). I want to use the email and password feature, but sign specific users in(the ones in my firebase console). I know this is a pretty broad question, but any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should check a documentation for Firebase. You can find on official Firebase website:
1. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users
2. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth

Then you should check [Firebase Authentication samples](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/auth) and look for **Email/Password Setup**.

Answer (score 0):

After you have created your project and added your app to it, you have to go to the console/auth/sign_in method and enable the email and password authentication. Then you have to create a activity/fragment to represent the login, sign up etc.

On the launcher activity you should have this method to check the state of current user and do the necessary action of `user != null` or if `user == null` based on your preferences.

```
FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authStateListener;
authStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
@Override
public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {

    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if (user != null){
        startActivity(new Intent(LoginPage.this,MainActivity.class));
    }


 }
}; 
auth.addAuthStateListener(authStateListener);//this one in onStart
```

then you can use these 2 methods for signin and create new user respectively

```
FirebaseAuth auth;
auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email , password)
 .addOnCompleteListener(LoginPage.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

        if (task.isSuccessful()){

        }else {

        }
      }
});


auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
 .addOnCompleteListener(SignUpPage.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

        if (task.isSuccessful()){

        }else {

        }

    }
});
```

go to all the links provided by mmBs and also see this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/06/android-getting-started-firebase-simple-login-registration-auth/) for a simple and working example